# Given a column of keys, overwrite it with a column of strings based on a dictionary

Tags: r, function, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
 n <- 15000
 key <- sample(1:10, 10)
 dictionary <- data.frame(key = key, value = LETTERS[1:10])

 target_df <- data.frame(code = sample(key, n, replace = TRUE))
 target_df$code[sample(seq_len(n), 10)] <- 0
```

I want to overwrite `code` with the corresponding `value`s from `dictionary`. What's an efficient **and** readable way to do it? I used

```
find_in_dictionary <- function(x) {
  y <- dictionary[match(x, dictionary[, 1]), 2]
}

target_df$code <- find_in_dictionary(target_df$code)
sum(is.na(target_df$code))
```

It seems to work fine, and it handles correctly the no-match cases. Do you have better suggestions?

Comment: @DeltalV: Kindly consider to upvote or accept the answer if the answer works for you :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using `sqldf`: 
Map `key`  and `value` by looking at `left join` in both `data.frame` based on `key`.

Before running this you need to just change the `colnames` of `target_df`.

```
colnames(target_df)<-c("key")
head(sqldf("Select t.key,d.value from target_df t LEFT JOIN dictionary d on (t.key=d.key)"))
```

Output:

```
   key value
1   1     I
2   3     B
3   1     I
4   5     C
5   2     F
6   7     E
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dplyr`'s `left_join` function. This is a SQL join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
n <- 15000
key <- sample(1:10, 10)
dictionary <- data.frame(key = key, value = LETTERS[1:10])

target_df <- data.frame(code = sample(key, n, replace = TRUE))
target_df$code[sample(seq_len(n), 10)] <- 0

target_df %>%
  arrange(code) %>%
  left_join(dictionary, by = c("code"="key")) %>%
  drop_na(.)-> final_df

head(final_df)
#>    code value
#> 11    1     I
#> 12    1     I
#> 13    1     I
#> 14    1     I
#> 15    1     I
#> 16    1     I

# final_df without 'order'
target_df %>%
  left_join(dictionary, by = c("code"="key")) %>%
  drop_na(.) %>%
  head(.)
#>   code value
#> 1    6     A
#> 2    6     A
#> 3    8     D
#> 4    7     F
#> 5    8     D
#> 6    9     H

final_df %>%
  select(value) %>%
  head(.)
#>    value
#> 11     I
#> 12     I
#> 13     I
#> 14     I
#> 15     I
#> 16     I
```

You could also use `data.table` package to achieve similar results. SO has many questions on that.

Created on 2018-08-30 by the reprex package (v0.2.0)

Comment: you missed the  `target_df$code[sample(seq_len(n), 10)] <- 0` part (which I used to make sure the solution handles non-matching cases correctly). However I added it to your code and it still works. Good job!

Comment: @Suhas Hedge: Could you please check your output? Something is wrong. Please verify your mapping with the `dictionary` `data.frame`.

Comment: @Suhas Hedge: If I am wrong then please feel free to correct me!

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan I saw it too after posting the answer. I think it is just how the values are being ordered. I haven't used an explicit ordering in my dplyr pipe. Would have to check it out though

Comment: and I missed `target_df$code[sample(seq_len(n), 10)] <- 0`